# Django Admin "Helper" Functionality Not Working on Server

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my localhost Django administrator I am able to fill-in Date and Time fields by clicking on the little "Date" and "Time" helper icons next to my pub_date field. However, the same administrator on my Server does NOT show these icons. The server-side admin also doesn't pop open a pop-up window for the little "+" plus sign for fields in related tables. Is there a server setting or something that I've missed?

BTW, my admin media directory is working correctly otherwise.

Thank you in advance!

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not serving javascript files properly. To have this functionality, proper javascript must loaded.